# How to remove a functionality attached to an element on document ready using jquery or javascript

Tags: jquery

The situation here is initially I am creating a div dynamically with an img attribute and setting it's source dynamically. Also on image load some functions are getting called. Later at some point of time if I change the image source of that particular div the same functions are getting called which is not desired.

```
$(function(){
// on doc ready I do this
  $('#inner').append("<div id='data-1'><img/></div>");
  $('#data-1').find('img').attr('src', dataArr['id'][1].img).load(function() {
    populateNavigationDots();
    $(".pagination span:first-child").addClass('swiper-active-switch');
  });// this works fine.
});
// later if I try to change the src attribute of the above image then the previous on     load functionality 'populateNavigationDots();' too works. How can I stop this
$('#data-1').find('img').attr('src','img/2.jpg');
```

Comment: `.off('load')`. http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: what you want to remove?

Comment: It's little bit weird of the way you use load function. It's this the ajax load of jQuery?

Comment: I am using the image load function call back of jquery

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
.off( events [, selector ] [, handler(eventObject) ] )
```

http://api.jquery.com/off/

Answer (score 0):

After image load I removed the load event handler using jquery off

$('#data-1').find('img').off('load');